# Error 401 when accessing Bing News API v7 using from Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, azure-cognitive-services, bing-news-search-api

I would like to use UnityEngine.Networking and StartCoroutine() to retrieve data from Bing API in Unity/C#. I am getting Error 401 which is:

```
{"error":{"code":"401","message": "Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource."}}
```

The url that I am attempting to call is:

```
https://[**MyEndpoint**]/bing/v7.0/news/trendingtopics?BingAPIs-Market=en-US&Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key=[**KEY**]
```

I assume the reason for rejection is that I explicitly added Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key header in the url but not sure %100.

Comment: The subscription key is a header and doesn't belong in the URL.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/bing-video-search/concepts/sending-requests

Comment: how's going? Has your issue been solved ?

Comment: @jdweng thanks for the help! I tried to read documentation before I posted this question, but I got confused due to the lack of knowledge that I have in C# and Azure, but I am sure I will get it one day! now I know header is not really belong in the URL so thanks for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jdweng indicated, you should specify your subscription key in the request header, just as below :
[image]

If it is necessary for you using the subscription key in the request URL,the param here should be `subscription-key` instead of `Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key` just as below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bing API is RESTful API and expects the authentication key in the request header